# What does C#'s Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr) mean in Delphi?

Tags: c#, delphi

I'm translating some C# code to Delphi, I understand that(msg = TMsg):

```
(int)msg.LParam
```

is just a cast(please correct me if I'm wrong), however the following boggles my mind:

```
Marshal.ReadInt32( (IntPtr)msg.WParam, 4 )
```

can someone please clarify this?

Comment: Thats reading an `int` from a pointer to an `int`. Seemingly as part of a windows message, probably in a `WndProc` override.

Comment: I would highly recommend taking a look at http://www.pinvoke.net/, there a lot of good examples of using IntPtr, Int, WParam etc.

Comment: That your mind is boggled does not naturally lead one to understand how to explain it to you. You say that the first is "just a cast" -- well, the cast in the second code fragment is also "just a cast", so what specifically do you find boggling about it?

Comment: @EricLippert I'm translating from C# to Delphi, not vice versa, so pinvoke won't really help...

Comment: I think somthing similar in Delphi might be `^(msg.WParam + 4)`

Comment: @Jodrell it seems that that's exactly what it is

Comment: @Jodrell Nearly, but the caret is in the wrong place, and you need a typecast.

Comment: @David Heffeman, oh well, that's my first line of Delphi ever.

Comment: @RobKennedy thank you for the edit, I was "too wired" to think of a proper title (:

Comment: [The Fine Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.readint32.aspx). Did you read it?

Comment: @user539484 no but thank you for the link and downvote (:

Comment: @DorinDuminica, you are welcome. Do you need anything else to be found in Google manually? ;-)

Comment: @user539484 If one is completely unfamiliar with .net and in particular how interop is handled, even the documentation of `Marshal.ReadInt32` may not fully explain things. Context is very  important.

Comment: Am I reading this question's C# code correctly? You still cast to pointer-types in C#?  Really?  The Msg.Wparam is holding a pointer to an integer value instead of passing the integer value through the message as a literal?  This looks like the return of "shoot self in foot" style C programming, in a supposedly "safe" language....  This C# code smells BAD to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, exactly. It is not clear what asked here: blind translation between languages, differences between managed/unmanaged data, or maybe differences between primitive values and interop pointers. See Eric Lippert's comment above.

Comment: @WarrenP It's probably just a cheap way to read a single field of a struct rather than going to the trouble of calling `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

Comment: @user539484 But you clearly understood what was being asked because you posted a link to the function that Dorin was not quite grokking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thats your conclusion :-P Where do you look when you feel an urge to know what time is it now? :-)

Comment: @WarrenP the code is a sample application(the only one) that came with an SDK, basically it imports functions from a dll so it has to do some so called "unsafe" calls, the code is in C#, very nice and easy to translate, but I ran over this which it turned out that my suspicion was "right", but it's not enough, I need as "near" as possible to the end result, I don't have the hardware "yet" and time is ticking ):

Comment: @user539484: outside at the sun (or the moon, or the stars)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That just reads a 4 byte integer from a pointer. In managed .net code you don't have pointers (unless you use unsafe code) so the framework provides tools to help interop between the native and managed world. The documentation on MSDN for the .net libraries is comprehensive and, of course, describes [`Marshal.ReadInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17bxe5tf.aspx).

The extra complication here is that there is an additional offset of 4 bytes. In reality the pointer is probably pointing to a struct and this code is picking out the integer value at offset 4 of the struct. That's overwhelmingly the most likely explanation for the code being the way it is.

Now, a literal translation would be:

```
PInteger(msg.WParam+4)^
```

but you might alternatively write it in Delphi like this:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
    i1: Integer;
    i2: Integer;
  end;
  PMyrecord = ^TMyRecord;
....
value := PMyRecord(msg.WParam)^.i2;
```

If you know which message this `WParam` relates to then you will also know what the true `record` is to use here. And so you would not need to define a dedicated record since `Windows.pas` would already do so.

Comment: +1 thank you David, so is this really just a PInteger(msg.WParam)^? that's what I originally suspected, but wasn't clear to me...

Comment: "In managed code you don't have pointers" - This is false.  You certainly can have pointers in every manged language I have ever used if you choose to do so.

Comment: @Dorin Not quite. There is an extra offset there. It is essentially `PInteger(msg.WParam+4)^`.

Comment: @Ramhound In unsafe code yes. In safe code, no. Or am I wrong here? And if so perhaps you can enlighten me.

Comment: @David yes, it's an offset of 4 bytes, thank you!!
btw. what's with the -1? your example is good and your comment completes it! accepted!